# symfony редактирование данных в форме

Tags: symfony

уважаемые знатоки symfony, хочу уточнить свой вопрос - есть данные по сотруднику, нужно осуществить возможность загружать и отображать фотографию на странице, где можно редактировать данные о сотруднике. Подключен бандл Vich UploaderBunlde. Форма редактирования

```
{{ form_start(edit_form) }
{{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
{{ form_end(edit_form) }
```

отображается поле загрузки файла, имя файла записывается в бд. Не получается отобразить фотографию. Попытки типа

```
<img src="{{asset(edit_form_row.avatar)}}"/>
```

безрезультатны,  возможно я вообще смотрю не в том направлении, очень мало опыта и очень мало литературы по symfony.
Еще один вопрос по фикстурах, если сущность содержит self-referencing

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Киньте весь код, относящийся к задаче, откликов и помощи будет больше.

Comment: откуда берется значение `edit_form_row` если форма вроде как называется `edit_form` ? И почему пытаететь получить ссылку на изображение из формы? Если это форма редактирования т.е. объект уже существует, то можно получить из самого объекта